# Android video player started using intent ,how to know when did the player stopped

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I started video player properly  but I could not find how to know if the Player got stopped or user stopped it , as on stopping the player I need to do some work.
After trying for lot I am posting please help.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(decfile.getPath()), "video/*"); 
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
startActivity(Intent intent)
```

you can use

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

or

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle bundle)
```

and override the event handler (your necessary listener)

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
```

See also:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(decfile.getPath()), "video/*"); 
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);

Comment: can I control the controls of the player started with this type

Comment: I'm afraid not. With this approach you can only know when the player (or exactly the Activity) is closed. If you want to control the playback you have to create your own activity and place a MediaPlayer on it (as @osayilgan said). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use your own activity to play videos. In your activity you can implement MediaPlayer's listeners and you can know when video finishes.

Implement a Media Player inside your activity ;

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(YourActivity.this);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(YourActivity.this);
```

and in onCompletion method

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

    // TODO
    // implement your logic here.
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this , At present I need to start with only using intent.

Comment: You have to create your own video player and perform action either on touch of surface or on pause button.

Comment: You don't have to implement it in your Current activity. Create another one named as VideoActivity. Then you can finish the activity whenever the video finishes, and you can go back to previous view.

Comment: There is no another way, as far as I know.

Comment: @osayilgan let me try with this and get back

Comment: @osayilgan I also tried this to solve similar issue , but I am unable to stop the fast forward feature using mediacontroller via setmediacontroller. can you help me in this case

Comment: @Meher I didn't use the MediaContoller View for my case. But for the Fast Forward Feature, I read something in developer website : "The "rewind" and "fastforward" buttons are shown unless requested otherwise by using the MediaController(Context, boolean) constructor with the boolean set to false". So if you don't want to use these feature you simply need to pass false into the Constructor of MediaController class.

Comment: I used MediaPlayer For Showing Video,But cant able to watch..It is stopped in "sendBroadcast android.media.IMediaPlayer.videoexist" Line..Can u help me for this???

Comment: @dya I'm not really sure about what you are experiencing. It's a totally different thing. Create a SOF question with more details and share the link here.